# What is difference between Active Directory Federation Services and Webserver IIS?

Tags: windows, active-directory, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs

In the Windows world, IIS is used to deploy a website or application and while going through ADFS links from Google I got a feeling that its also allowing user to access web application.

What's the difference between two of them, while logging inside ADFS what users can access irrespective of application?

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful ,  any place to start

Comment: ADFS is an authetication gateway webservice, IIS is just a webserver. Which is commonly used to host ADFS.

Answer (score 2):

[Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services) is a software component to provide users with Single Sign-On (SSO) access to systems and applications located across different system, whereby the Internet Information Service (IIS) is a webserver.